# Get unique values, sum and count from an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array where I would like to get the unique values and the number of their occurrences, and sum the matching company names. I'm using lodash, and so far I'm able to get each unique value.

How can i efficiently get the number of each occurrence, and sum them? Price data is strings.

```
var data = [
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100.5"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Google", "price": "100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price": "100"}
];
```

Result I need:

```
Company | Count | Sum
Apple   |   3   | 300.5
Google  |   1   | 100
```

My code so far:

```
var result = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, 'company'), function (item) {
  $('table').append('<tr><td>'+item.company+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Is it possible to do sum and count inside the same _.map function?

Answer (score 5):

*Pure JS*(*Ecmascript5*) solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Object.keys()` functions:

```js
var data = [
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100.5"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Google", "price": "100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price": "100"}
], rows = "";

var result = data.reduce(function(r, o) {
    if (r[o.company]){
        ++r[o.company].count;
        r[o.company].price += Number(o.price);
    } else {
        r[o.company] = {count: 1, price: Number(o.price)};
    }
    return r;
}, {});

Object.keys(result).forEach(function(name){
  rows += '<tr><td>'+ name +'</td>' + 
          '<td>'+ result[name].count +'</td>' +
          '<td>'+ result[name].price +'</td></tr>';

});
$('table').append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>Sum</th>
  </tr>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first `groupBy` company and then `map` and `reduce` to return array of objects for each company.

```js
var data = [
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100.5"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price":"100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Google", "price": "100"},
 {"cat":"IT","company":"Apple", "price": "100"}
];

var group = _.groupBy(data, 'company')

var result = _.map(_.keys(group), function(e) {
  return _.reduce(group[e], function(r, o) {
    return r.count += +o.price, r
  }, {Company: e, count: 0, sum: group[e].length})
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using this and get an ESLint warning "Unexpected use of comma operator". It works, how can I get rid of this warning? Thanks

Comment: @user3808307 comma probably doesn't do what you expect it to. In most languages, this returns multiple values, but in Javascript the comma just returns the second value.

This would be better written `r.count += +o.price; return r`